# Is there a way for google cloud storage client to point to 'file object' on cloud storage to be then used by lxml?

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage, lxml

With Google Cloud Storage Client I could not read a Storage file as an object as required by the lxml.etree.parse. I could read the Cloud storage file as a blob, but that did not work well with lxml.

I am trying to convert XML files using an XSLT file. I want to have a Google Cloud Function(in Python3.7) that will be triggered as soon as the XML file is uploaded to Cloud Storage. I have tried this code by storing the files locally and it works. However need a way to get this working with Cloud Storage as well.

```
----Using local files (Working Code):
import lxml.etree as ET
filename = "C:\\GCP\\Files\\Profile.xml"
xsltfile = "C:\\GCP\\Files\\Transform.xslt"
outpath = "C:\\GCP\\Files\\Output\\Output.json"

dom = ET.parse(filename)
xslt = ET.parse(xsltfile)
transform = ET.XSLT(xslt)
newdom = transform(dom)
xdom = str(newdom)

text_file = open(outpath, "w")
text_file.write(xdom)
text_file.close()

----Using Cloud storage(not working):
from google.cloud import storage
import lxml.etree as ET

client = storage.Client()
bucket = client.get_bucket('customerfile02')
xmlblob = bucket.blob('testprofile.xml')
inputxml=xmlblob.download_as_string()
xmldom = ET.parse(inputxml)

Error: failed to load external entity
```

The error is expected as I am passing an XML string instead of a File Object as expected by ET.parse
How can I pass a file object from Cloud storage to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `lxml.etree.parse()` function expects a string as a filename. If you want to pass it file contents instead, you need to wrap it in a `StringIO` or `BytesIO` (in this case, the latter):

```
from io import BytesIO
from google.cloud import storage
import lxml.etree as ET

client = storage.Client()
bucket = client.get_bucket('customerfile02')
xmlblob = bucket.blob('testprofile.xml')
inputxml = xmlblob.download_as_string()
xmldom = ET.parse(BytesIO(inputxml))
```

See the `lxml` documentation here: https://lxml.de/parsing.html.

Comment: Thanks Dustin for your idea on this. I tried with this code and get the below error with the ET.parse statement   "TypeError: initial_value must be str or None, not bytes"

Comment: Looks like `inputxml` is actually bytes and not a string, see my update.

Comment: Thanks Dustin. This works. I will further try to use this with ET.XSLT to do the transformation.